# Zip files and sub folder into muliple zips and keep the same folder structure while unzip it

Tags: unix

Using UNIX SHELL SCRIPT

want to zip more than 50GB to 100 GB (files and sub folders)

multiple subfolders and files from the ROOT folder.

But i want to split and save multiple zips - the challenge is
i have to keep the same folder structure while unzip it.

how to build the split Zip files and how to keep the same structure.

Comment: Better add examples. The output of `tree` from the structure is a good idea. And add expected hierarchy.

Comment: Do you want to split your archive into multiple `.zip` files for ease of transferring? The `zip` command allows for that using the `-s` or `--split-size` option. For example, `zip -r --split-size 50m my_archive.zip path1 path2 path3` will compress the files hierarchy under `path1`, `path2` and `path3` into as many 50Mb zip files as necessary.  See `man zip` and look for `--spit-size`.

Comment: Do you want to split your archive into multiple .zip files for ease of transferring?  - YES, Let me try that option ...while split as multiple zips ...the extension getting different instead of ZIP

Comment: after did the below comment                                                                                      
  zip -s 1g -r archivename.zip directory_name                                                               
 it produced the below                                                                               
 archivename.zip
archivename.z01
archivename.z02
archivename.z03
archivename.z04